# Adding Archive to Libre Office using Docker

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, libreoffice

In one folder I have two files: Dockerfile and postgresql-42.2.4.jar

**Dockerfile:**

```
from ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libreoffice-base

COPY postgresql-42.2.4.jar postgresql-42.2.4.jar

CMD ["usr/bin/libreoffice"]
```

**postgresql-42.2.4.jar:**

I downloaded PostgreSQL JDBC archive from [PostgreSQL official site](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html)

To run docker I used:

```
docker build -t gui-app .
```

then:

```
docker run --net=host --env="DISPLAY" --volume="$HOME/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:rw" gui-app
```

Libre Office run correctly, but when I want to add Class Path ([link to Libre help site](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Class_Path)) I can't find .jar file which I copied in Dockerfile.

I didn't manually install JRE, but I think JRE is build in ubuntu.

Why I can't find JDBC archive file?
[image: scrrenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no JRE installed by default in the docker image `ubuntu:16.04`. You can inspect the list of installed packages by running:

```
docker run -it ubuntu:16.04 apt list
```

You can install the default JRE in your Dockerfile by adding the `default-jre` package:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libreoffice-base default-jre

COPY postgresql-42.2.4.jar postgresql-42.2.4.jar

CMD ["usr/bin/libreoffice"]
```